# Как узнать подходит ли сетка Bootstrap для присланого макета псд?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Допустим, сложилась ситуация,когда прислали макет псд страницы которую нужно адаптировать под мобильные устройства.
Но допустим,нет возможности узнать у дизайнера создавал ли он макет с учетом возможности использования бутстраповской сетки или нет.

Вопрос такой возник после прочтения данной статьи где говорилось что если дизайнер не создавал макет с использованием 12 колоночной сетки то возможности использовать бутстраповской сетки нет.
http://frontender.info/whats-wrong-with-jquery-and-bootstrap

То как тогда можно узнать ,возможно ли использовать бутстрап?

А вот еще тема,где я вывесил пример макета(там немного другой вопрос),кстати,его можно адаптировать бутстрапом?
http://www.cyberforum.ru/html/thread1907947.html

Comment: Непонятен вопрос. Вы хотите узнать, какими хаками можно воспользоваться, чтобы таки натянуть на bootstrap макет, неподходящий для этого фреймворка?

Comment: В ответе привели сайт, там всё настраивается прекрасно: http://joxi.ru/1A5Jy05fnGgJ4r

Comment: @Arhad
Вот тут пример макета там видна сетка дизайнера,
но вообще я не знаю как обозначаются колонки(каким цветом) ,то ли голубой цвет-это и эсть колонка,после него пробел непонятно что обозначает тоже колонку или отступ.

Вообще главный вопрос--как узнать подходит ли бутстрап для адаптации макета который прислали,но нет инфы от дизайнера делался ли макет под бутстрап и возможно ли его использование если макет не создавался с учетом сетки бутстрапа.

А вообще. я же ссылки оставил на начальном посту о статье в которой говориться что не все макеты можно адаптировать сеткой бутстрапа.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите, на моем скриншоте вам видна сетка? в вашем макете такая есть? Сетки разные бывает, пользуйтесь линейкой(например в фотошопе,чтобы измерить ширину макета, отступов, колонок и т.д. В **Bootstrap 3** можно настраивать(подключать только то,что необходимо, и менять ширину контейнера), смотрите ***[Здесь](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)*** раздел **Grid system**

[image: Пример сетки Bootstrap]

Comment: там есть фото макета(сделал скрин в фотошопе),но я не знаю как обозначены колонки (голубым цветом чтоль?)
http://www.cyberforum.ru/html/thread1907947.html

Но главный вопрос в следующем,а если прысылают макет не в псд формате а в ДЖПГ без какой либо сетки то как узнать подходит ли бутстрап для адаптации?

Comment: Конечно нужно **измерять** ширину колонок, отступов и т.д. - так найдете ответ. Ссылку на Customize бутстрапа я вам выше дал, но вы видимо ее не смотрели.  **jpg** это уже не макет, а просто картинка; остается разве на глаз прикидывать(в бутстрапе 12 колонок), некоторые секции например сделать бутстрапом, а некоторые просто через медиа запросы.